# CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC with a single call

Tags: c

I use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsp1)` and `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsp2)`, one after another. Can I do it with a single call to reduce the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard, portable way to do this - `clock_gettime` is based on operating system functionality that doesn't support this sort of "multi-query". Extending this functionality is non-trivial - and might require developing a driver that will expose this functionality for you.

---

Specifically on Linux, this might be relatively easy and does not require writing a driver.

On Linux, `clock_gettime` doesn't actually call into the kernel - it makes use of [vdso](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) which allows the kernel to expose information to user-space without having to switch to kernel mode. The classic example of this usage is functions like `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime` - these aren't privileged functions (with the exception of `CLOCK_REALTIME`, which does require some privileges) and the information can be made available to userspace for efficiency purposes.

You can leverage `vdso` to access the data directly yourself - have a look at functions in [`/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/vdso/gettimeofday.c#L110) - which access the tables exposed to `vdso` to fetch the current time. I linked specifically to `do_hres` which seems to be the function that accesses the timestamps directly.

By accessing the `vdso` tables yourself you are minimizing overhead and reducing the difference between your two calls.